# FASM - Winsock, reconnection issue

Tags: connection, client, winsock, fasm

I am learning assembly and trying to write a simple WinSock app in educational means.
 Although mostly everything works fine, I am having an issue when trying to reconnect;

```
start: 
invoke WSAStartup,200,wsadata
invoke socket,AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0
mov [hSock],eax
invoke htons, PORTCONST
mov [sadr.sin_port], ax
mov [sadr.sin_family], AF_INET
invoke  inet_addr, IP
mov [sadr.sin_addr], eax
Connectl:
invoke connect,[hSock], sadr, 16
cmp eax, 0
je Recievel
invoke Sleep, 1000
jmp Connectl
Recievel:
invoke recv, [hSock], spacket, 131, 0
cmp eax, 0
jng Clsl
{Some non-related code}
jmp Recievel
Clsl:
mov [spacket.command],0
invoke CloseSocket, [hSock]
invoke WSACleanUp
invoke Sleep, 4000
jmp start
```

Everything is okay when I run this client while server app is not ran, but when I do the same while it is ran or close server app and run it again, I am getting quiet weird issue:
 It starts to reconnect a lot of times, and at some point in time it "successes", but I can't send anything from server app to client and vice versa.

Comment: I have found out the solution on my own.
 By some reason if I test on my localhost, due to too small latency between client and server something gets messed up, while if I add additional sleep in recv procedure OR use it on any other PC - everything goes OK.

Comment: It's shame you deleted your Delphi question now. I was in the middle of answering it. Contrary to what others said, the error in the code was clear. If you un-deleted it, I could put you right.